# Twilio/Dropwizard runtime error

Tags: java, twilio, dropwizard

I am trying to get Twilio to work in a Dropwizard application.  The program compiles, but I am constantly getting the following failure when bootstrapping the server.

```
$ sudo ./startpiservice.sh
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:  com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/ReferenceType at  com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.guava.GuavaModule.setupModule(GuavaModule.java:55 ) at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:550) at io.dropwizard.jackson.Jackson.configure(Jackson.java:54) at io.dropwizard.jackson.Jackson.newObjectMapper(Jackson.java:24) at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.<init>(Bootstrap.java:64) at io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:72) at applicationconfiguration.HomeApplication.main(HomeApplication.java:71) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.ReferenceType at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ... 7 more
```

The whole file can be found here on my Dropbox...sorry I am at my day job, and can't access GitHUb to upload this there.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/or5v14uyyjplvmr/AAB4uoHdRDYLZVylUfGNotkfa?dl=0

The class in question is SMSResource.java at     \pirestservice\src\main\java\resources\SMSResource.java

The code compiles and runs without any of the code statements and imports for Twilio, but once I use the import statements and the code statements, the program fails during bootstrap.

I am relatively new to using Maven and Dropwizard...is this an issue with dependencies conflicting?  Am I missing something?  The Twilio code works in a simple stand alone program...but not in Dropwizard.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~UPDATE MARCH 2, 2017~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Per the recommendation by hortega, I modified my Maven POM file and the program compiled and when deployed my server runs.  All the method calls work except the one I need which is "/sendsms".  Here is the part of the POM file, java class file, and the stacktrace.

```
<!-- Twilio -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
    <version>(7.0,7.9)</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

package resources;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import com.twilio.Twilio;
import com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.Message;
import com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber;

import authentication.User;
import database.AccountDAO;
import database.UserDAO;
import io.dropwizard.hibernate.UnitOfWork;


/**
 * This class defines the URLs and provides the interface to HTTP requests and works
 * with the class PiGpioService to set and retrieve information from the model.
 */
@Path("/smsnotification")
@RolesAllowed("ADMIN")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class SMSResource implements GpioObserver
{
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SMSResource.class);
    private final AccountDAO accountDAO;
    private final UserDAO userDAO;
    private int count;
    private Timer timer;
    private boolean timerSet = false;

    public SMSResource(AccountDAO accountDAO, UserDAO userDAO)
    {
        this.accountDAO = accountDAO;
        this.userDAO = userDAO;
    }

    /**
     * method called by GpioRepresentation class when there is a
     * change in state on garage door.
     * @param String state
     */
    public void update(String state)
    {   
        //if state is HIGH trigger a timer to start.  Kill the timer if
        //the state is low.
        if(state.equals("HIGH"))
        {
            //conditional to prevent multiple Timer objects
            if(!timerSet)
            {
                timer = new Timer();
                int delay = (20 * 60 * 1000);
                int period = (20 * 60 * 1000);

                //schedule first message to be sent when door is open 20 minutes.
                //then send a message every 20 minutes to a maximum of
                //3 times.
                MessageExecutor msgExec = new MessageExecutor();
                timer.schedule(msgExec, delay, period);
                timerSet = true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //cancel timer if the garage door is closed and reset the count
            timer.cancel();
            count = 0;
            timerSet = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Send an SMS text message.
     * FOR TESTING ONLY
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/sendsms")
    @UnitOfWork
    public Response sendSMSMessage()
    {
        List<User> users;
        List<TwilioAccount> accountDetails;
        int index = 0;

        users = userDAO.getAllUsers();
        accountDetails = accountDAO.getAccountDetails(); 

        Twilio.init(accountDetails.get(index).getSID(), accountDetails.get(index).getToken()); 

        for(User u : users)
        {
            LOGGER.info("SendSMS URL Works and I can get my USER and TWILIO Details,"
                    + "User {}, phone number {}, SID = {}, token = {}, from# = {}.", 
                    u.getName(), u.getPhoneNumber(), accountDetails.get(index).getSID(), accountDetails.get(index).getToken(),
                    accountDetails.get(index).getPhoneNumber());

            Message message = Message
                    .creator(new PhoneNumber(u.getPhoneNumber()), new PhoneNumber(accountDetails.get(index).getPhoneNumber()),
                        "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?")
                    .setMediaUrl("https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg")
                    .create();

        }

        return Response.ok("message(s) sent").build();
    }

    /**
     * This private (inner) class is responsible for initiating a message
     * being sent every 20 minutes to alert that the garage door has been
     * left open.
     */
    private class MessageExecutor extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        @UnitOfWork
        public void run()
        {

            if(count < 3)
            {
                List<User> users;
                List<TwilioAccount> accountDetails;
                int index = 0;

                users = userDAO.getAllUsers();
                accountDetails = accountDAO.getAccountDetails(); 

                //Twilio.init(accountDetails.get(index).getSID(), accountDetails.get(index).getToken());

                for(User u : users)
                {
                    LOGGER.info("SendSMS URL Works and I can get my USER and TWILIO Details,"
                            + "User {}, phone number {}, SID = {}, token = {}, from# = {}.", 
                            u.getName(), u.getPhoneNumber(), accountDetails.get(index).getSID(), accountDetails.get(index).getToken(),
                            accountDetails.get(index).getPhoneNumber());

                    //Message message = Message
                      //      .creator(new PhoneNumber(u.getPhoneNumber()), new PhoneNumber(accountDetails.get(index).getPhoneNumber()),
                        //        "This is the ship that made the Kessel Run in fourteen parsecs?")
                          //  .setMediaUrl("https://c1.staticflickr.com/3/2899/14341091933_1e92e62d12_b.jpg")
                            //.create();

                }
                count++;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

And here is the stacktrace/logger output:

```
INFO  [2017-03-03 02:14:29,347] authentication.BasicAuthenticator: User: Mike logged in with email: mike@xxxxxxx.ca and password: xxxxxx.
INFO  [2017-03-03 02:14:29,374] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener: Session Metrics {
    531871 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    5236262 nanoseconds spent preparing 1 JDBC statements;
    6003028 nanoseconds spent executing 1 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
INFO  [2017-03-03 02:14:29,571] resources.SMSResource: SendSMS URL Works and I can get my USER and TWILIO Details,User Mike, phone number +1xxxxxxxxxx, SID = ACxxxxxxxxxxxxx, token = 1xxxxxxxxxx5, from# = +1xxx5xx8xx9.
INFO  [2017-03-03 02:14:37,092] org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener: Session Metrics {
    526871 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    5925736 nanoseconds spent preparing 2 JDBC statements;
    6532189 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    29239673 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 2 entities and 2 collections)
}
ERROR [2017-03-03 02:14:37,113] io.dropwizard.jersey.errors.LoggingExceptionMapper: Error handling a request: 0cd82e2d769a36c4
! com.twilio.exception.ApiException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
! at com.twilio.http.NetworkHttpClient.makeRequest(NetworkHttpClient.java:89)
! at com.twilio.http.HttpClient.reliableRequest(HttpClient.java:38)
! at com.twilio.http.HttpClient.reliableRequest(HttpClient.java:22)
! at com.twilio.http.TwilioRestClient.request(TwilioRestClient.java:42)
! at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:307)
! at com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.MessageCreator.create(MessageCreator.java:25)
! at com.twilio.base.Creator.create(Creator.java:45)
! at resources.SMSResource.sendSMSMessage(SMSResource.java:139)
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
! at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
! at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
! at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1689)
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:34)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:50)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:44)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1676)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1174)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1106)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:240)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:51)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:459)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:68)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:56)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:169)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:524)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:319)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:253)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
192.168.1.224 - - [03/Mar/2017:02:14:37 +0000] "GET /smsnotification/sendsms HTTP/1.1" 500 110 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36" 8177
```

I am pretty done for the night banging my head against the wall....If anyone can offer suggestions, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing jackson dependecy. Add this to your pom.xml

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-guava -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-guava</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will implement this tonight or tomorrow when I get home and let you know how things worked out.

Comment: I added these dependencies, but the application still crashes during bootstrap.  Exact same errors.  :-(

Answer (score 0):

Two of your dependencies are pulling different versions of the Jackson library. Here `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` is your friend, it will tell you which dependencies are clashing:

```
...
[INFO] +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-core:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.dropwizard:dropwizard-util:jar:1.0.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.7.8:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4.3)
...
[INFO] \- com.twilio.sdk:twilio:jar:7.5.0:compile
...
[INFO]    +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.4.3:compile
[INFO]    |  +- (com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.4.0:compile - omitted for conflict with 2.4.3)
...
```

You can see here that `dropwizard-core` and `twilio` are using different versions of different Jackson packages. Usually, when you see this, there is a good chance Maven is using the wrong version, because it doesn't have enough information. So we should tell it which version of Jackson to use (generally we choose the latest version). There are a few ways to do it:

1. Dependency management: Adding the clashing dependencies inside this block allows you to choose their version for the whole project. Add the next block outside of `<dependencies>`:

   ```
   <dependencyManagement>
       <dependencies>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
               <version>2.7.8</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
               <version>2.7.8</version>
           </dependency>
           <dependency>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
               <version>2.7.8</version>
           </dependency>
       </dependencies>
   </dependencyManagement>
   ```
2. Exclude packages on your dependencies: This way gives you a more fine-grained control. Just add the `<exclusions>` block inside the dependency you want those packages version ignored. In this case that would be Twilio, as it has the oldest version of the clashing library.

   ```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.twilio.sdk</groupId>
       <artifactId>twilio</artifactId>
       <version>7.5.0</version>
       <exclusions>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
           <exclusion>
               <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
               <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
       </exclusions>
   </dependency>
   ```

When you start with Maven this issue will bite you a few times, but the `dependencies` plugin is really helpful here.

I've created a PR on [twilio-java](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java) to upgrade those dependencies, but if you don't want to wait just use one of the methods above.

[About Maven's dependency mechanism](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Comment: Thank you.  Your suggestions worked and I can compile and run the server, however,  I am getting another error.  I will edit my post with the stack trace and the java class file.

Answer (score 0):

I found the real answer to this question.  The issue lies within the JVM supplied in the distribution of Ubuntu Mate for Raspberry Pi.  They supply OpenJDK.  After much online debugging I started looking at the OS and the JVM as a source of my problems, and when I swapped out OpenJDK for Oracle JDK everything worked the way I expected it too.